# CreateOrUpdate AAD list

Tags: json, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am looking for an example, or examples, of CreateOrUpDate listing AAD objects.
I will probably schedule this as a nightly job too.
I am looking to add this to a task in my YAML Azure pipeline file.

I am totally new to CreateOrUpdate so any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Azure cli commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest) to create or update AAD objects. There are many examples in the document:

For example, to create a AAD Application with command `az ad app create`:

```
az ad app create --display-name my-native --native-app --required-resource-accesses @manifest.json
```

To create an AAD user with command `az ad user create`:

```
az ad user create –display-name psmith –password password –user-principal-name username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
```

To create an Service principal with command `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"`

To use above azure cli command in your Yaml azure pipeline, You need to use [Azure CLI Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops). And you need to create a [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager) to connect your azure devops project to your Azure subscription.  See steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) to create a service connection.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az --version
      az account show
```

If you are familiar with powershell scripts, You can also check out [azure powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) which can be used in [Azure Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) to create or update AAD objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I will look into this.